# How do I show a range of numerical values first in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

How would I arrange this so that it is still ordered by time but also any IDs under 10 would be shown first?

```
Time  |   ID
9:15  |   1
9:20  |   5
9:25  |   12
9:30  |   3
9:35  |   26
9:40  |   22
9:45  |   15
```

Can this be achieved with an "order by" code? Or do I need something else?

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

**EDIT: This is the output I'm hoping for:**

```
Time  |   ID
9:15  |   1
9:20  |   5
9:30  |   3   
9:25  |   12
9:35  |   26
9:40  |   22
9:45  |   15
```

ID 12 and 3 would be switched. So the priority would be on ID number THEN time.

Comment: What output do you expect ? The provided data can't be ordered further, as time values are unique.

Comment: I don't get your question. Do you want to order it by time and then by ID(but only if ID<10)?

Comment: Sorry, I made an edit. Basically I want to sort by ID first but only for IDs up to a certain number. The second sort would be Time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this custom sort

```
SELECT *
FROM   Yourtable
ORDER  BY CASE
            WHEN id <= 10 THEN id
            ELSE 11-- Just a number greater then 10 to keep the id>10 after id<=10
          END ASC,
          time
```

### Demo

**Schema setup**

```
create table #tts(Time  time,   ID int)
insert #tts values
('9:00' ,21 )
('9:15' ,1 ),
('9:20' ,5  ),
('9:25' ,12),
('9:30' ,3  ),
('9:35' ,26),
('9:40' ,22),
('9:45' ,15)
```

**Query**

```
SELECT *
FROM   #tts
ORDER  BY CASE
            WHEN id <= 10 THEN id
            ELSE 11
          END ASC,
          time
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is exactly what I need. I was thinking it would involve < and = but I didn't know how to incorporate them. I'm new so I can't vote it up, but this is probably it.

Right now I just have to sort out "ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator."

Comment: I'm actually getting the following error for the "END ASC" line:   

"ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator."

Comment: @Bill - looks like you are executing some other query can you post that query

Comment: @Bill - It is very clear that you modified the above query by adding `UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT`. It is a new question

Comment: It's pretty long. Should I just edit my current post to include it or post a new question?

Comment: @Bill - Post it as a new question

Answer (score 1):

A nested query with ORDER BY can work as well, though you will end up with a 3rd  sort column:

```
SELECT t.* FROM
( SELECT Time
        ,ID
        ,CASE WHEN ID < 10 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS 'ColOrder'
  FROM YourTable) as t
ORDER BY t.ColOrder, t.Time
```